# WebBrowser custom contextmenu not working if code within the browser's document disables right-click

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a ContextMenu on my Form attached to my WebBrowser and `IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled` on my WebBrowser is set to false as I want to only display my custom ContextMenu.

The issue is some websites like to disable right-clicking via the use of javascript (usually on videos or if they don't want text to be copied), and this seems to be preventing my WebBrowser control from receiving the right-click event to activate the custom ConextMenu.

Comment: That's interesting... I wonder if you could use `WebBrowser.InvokeScript` to re-enable right-click via JavaScript.